# SQL Server : get value from another table, make calculation and save to table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 1.8M records. I need to use column values from table to make calculation and save it to another table. I tried in C# but it is soooo slow to insert one by one. BulkCopy option is not a good solution for my project either. I don't have any experience with SQL queries.

**Table1**

```
Id int
x float
y float

Id    x       y
--------------------
1     45.55   25.15
2     65.45   35.66
3     33.25   42.49
```

I want to use x, y values for my calculation and save it to Table2

```
xx = 175 * (180 + x)
yy = 175 * (90 - y)
```

**Table2**

```
Id  int
xx  int
yy  int
```

In my c# code

```
int xx = (int)((175) * (180 + node.x));
int yy = (int)((175) * (90 - node.y));
```

Then I save it with insert in foreach loop, but it takes forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet here would be a SQL query, but I would make certain you have applied an index to your table1 so that it speeds up the process.

As for the query - put this into a new query window in SQL Server Management Studio and ensure your database is the default source.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (xx, yy)
    SELECT 
        CAST((175 * (180 + x)) AS INT) AS xx, 
        CAST((175 * (90 - y)) AS INT) AS yy 
    FROM
        table1
```

Please note the as xx and as yy are not necessary as you already have defined table headers for Table2.

Cast converts the overall answer of the sum into an integer - I have found that conversions to an integer when doing an insert can be a bit sketchy at times so doing the conversion prior to the insert can make things easier.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am receiving following error. Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Tabke2' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: Okay, so in Table2, you have an identity column - I assume the same is the case for Table1, so I've adjusted my answer above.

Comment: Yes, I have on both :) Sorry didn't mention about it.

Comment: Not a problem :)